# R - increase the font size of the numeric value in likert graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, likert

[image]

I want to increase the font size of those percentage values inside the graph. For example, those 56%, 19%, 25%.

Current code I use

```
Q5 <- likert(tmp)
plot(Q5, ordered=FALSE)  + theme(aspect.ratio=0.3, legend.text =element_text(color="black",size=8), axis.text=element_text(color="black",size=12))
```

I tried to add cex=5 inside plot function, but no effect at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using the `likert` package, you can set the size of the text labels with the `text.size` argument:

```
plot(Q5, text.size=5, ordered=FALSE)
```

You can see a description of the various options for likert plots by running `?likert.options`.

Comment: Very useful. It's not clear that likert.options is for information purposes only, and I spent ages trying to figure out how to use it.